# Chrome does not show Website

Tags: php, google-chrome, cakephp, xampp

I've a very mysterious problem and hope you can help me.
I'm developing a Website with CakePHP and using Chrome as my default Browser. As webserver I use XAMPP on my localhost.
Until today the website still worked in Chrome (there is nothing special for any browser programmed). But suddenly Chrome shows only a blank page:

```
<html><head><style type="text/css"></style></head><body></body></html>
```

In Firefox and IE the Site still works.

I havn't got a clue whats going wrong. I tried to delete cache, cookies, restarted the server, tested it in incognito mode. But nothing has changed.

Comment: What versions of mentioned software do you use? What code should be displayed? Some more information to possible reproduce the problem might help to get some more insights.

Comment: Chrome: 32.0.1700.107 m
XAMPP Version 1.8.3

Comment: Well, you'll have to do some more debugging, check the exact server response using the network console (or even better an external debug proxy like for example [**charles**](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)), and in case the response is really such a blank page, then add debug output in the code (from app to core) to check if and where exactly something brakes. ps. please always mention your exact CakePHP version!